# Cambiar icono de aplicacion hecha en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, icons

Estoy intentando agregar un icono a mi aplicación de netbenas. Estoy usando la herramienta de netbeans que te ayuda a crear una interfaz gráfica.

Me marca un error, la trama es

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:232)
    at martinez.adrian.contactosdbs.Base.<init>(Base.java:20)
    at martinez.adrian.contactosdbs.Base$2.run(Base.java:133)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

para ellos estoy utilizando el siguiente código.

```
> public class Base extends javax.swing.JFrame {
>
> 
> /**
>  * Creates new form Base
>  */
> public Base() {
>     initComponents();
>     setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/saitama.png")).getImage());
>     
> }
```

Cabe aclarar que ya ingresé la imagen a la carpeta src con el mismo nombre.

Tambien intente crear una carpeta otro paquete en el que agregue las imagenes, y coloque como ruta "/imagenes/saitama.png".

Comment: Hola Adrian, en **setIconImage( new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/saitama.png" )).getImage() );** te estaría sobrando el **.getImage());**.

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar `.getClassLoader()` para cargar correctamente el recurso.

```
 setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("saitama.png")).getImage());
```

Si deseas cargar tu imagen desde un directorio "imagenes", tu imagen debe encontrarse dentro de  `src/main/imagenes/saitama.png` en tu proyecto.

```
  setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("imagenes/saitama.png")).getImage());
```

Comment: Intente los dos métodos, pero creo que debe ser un problema con mi proyecto ya que intente poner otras imágenes con otros métodos en otros elementos y también me da error. Pero seguiré intentando. Muchas gracias por los comentarios